# How to convert a primal LP into the dual LP without usage of the standard form?

Tags: linear-programming

To understand the conversion without standard form I read: [Directly from primal to dual when primal not in standard form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/249413/directly-from-primal-to-dual-when-primal-not-in-standard-form)

The posted LP there is:
$$
        Primal =\begin{Bmatrix}
        max \ \ \ \  2x_1 - 2x_2 +x_3 + 4x_4  \\
        s.t. \ \ \ \ x_1 - x_2 - x_3 \ge 3\\
        \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ -x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \ge -3\\
        \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ + x_3 + 3x_4 \le 2\\
        \ -5x_1 + 5x_2 + 4x_3 + x_4 = 10\\
        \ \ \ \ x_1, x_2, x_3 \geq 0\\
        \end{Bmatrix}
$$

The corrected dual:

\begin{array}{rlrrrrr}
    \min        & 3y_1 & -3y_2&+2y_3&+10y_4 \\
    \mbox{s.t.} & y_1 &-y_2 && -5y_4&\geq& 2\\
       &-y_1&+y_2&&+5y_4&\geq& -2\\
       &-y_1&+y_2&+y_3&+4y_4&\geq& 3\\
       &&&3y_3&+y_4&=& 4\\
       &y_1& &&& \leq & 0 \\
                      &&y_2&&& \leq& 0 \\ &&&y_3 &&\geq & 0\\
                         &&&& y_4 && free
    \end{array}

I also read [Duality. Is this the correct Dual to this Primal L.P.?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234575/duality-is-this-the-correct-dual-to-this-primal-l-p/239045#239045).

With the comment I tried to solve the LP.
But I don't understand why the third constraint of the Dual LP is $-y_1+y_2+y_3+4y_4\geq 3$ and not $-y_1+y_2+y_3+4y_4\geq 1$.

Is greater than or equal to 3 really correct, and if so, why?

I've also put this LP [into a solver](https://cbom.atozmath.com/CBOM/Simplex.aspx?q=pd&q1=4%604%60MAX%60Z%60x1%2Cx2%2Cx3%2Cx4%602%2C-2%2C1%2C4%601%2C-1%2C-1%2C0%3B-1%2C1%2C1%2C0%3B0%2C1%2C0%2C3%3B-5%2C5%2C4%2C1%60%3E%3D%2C%3E%3D%2C%3C%3D%2C%3D%603%2C-3%2C2%2C10%60%60D%60false%60true%60false%60true%60false%60false%60true%601&dp=4&do=1#PrevPart), so it seems like it should be 1 and not 3.

Comment: Yes, the $3$ appears to be a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in calling out the constraint $-y_1+y_2+y_3+4y_4\geq 1$, as it shouldn't be $-y_1+y_2+y_3+4y_4\geq 3$. Thus, it appears to be a typo on OP's part.

For the future, an easier way to intuitively convert primal-dual problems is via the [S.O.B. method](https://scholarship.claremont.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1362&context=hmc_fac_pub). See [this as well](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/239045/1105283).

\begin{matrix}
&\text{Primal Problem} && \text{Dual Problem}\\
&\text{(or Dual Problem)} && \text{(or Primal Problem)}\\
\\
&\text{Maximization} && \text{Minimization}\\
\text{Sensible} & \le\text{ Constraint} & \text{Paired With} & \text{Non-Negative Variable}\\
\text{Odd}      & =\text{ Constraint}   & \text{Paired With} & \text{Unconstrained Variable}\\
\text{Bizzare}  & \ge\text{ Constraint} & \text{Paired With} & \text{Non-Positive Variable}
\\\\
\text{Sensible} &\text{Non-Negative Variable} & \text{Paired With} &\ge\text{ Constraint}\\
\text{Odd}      &\text{Unconstrained Variable} & \text{Paired With} &=\text{ Constraint}\\
\text{Bizzare}  &\text{Non-Positive Variable} & \text{Paired With} &\le\text{ Constraint}\\
\\
\end{matrix}