# Two forms of duality in linear programming

Tags: linear-programming

I do not know much about this subject, but I am trying to learn a little.

In a book I have it says that a primal problem is:

> max $c'X$
>
> subject to
>
> $AX \ge b$
>
> $X \ge 0$

It says that the dual of this is:

> maximize  $b'Y$
>
> subject to:
>
> $A'y \le c$
>
> $Y \ge 0$

However they did not prove the linear programming duality theorem.

However I found another text where they do this, but there they use that:

> max $c'X$
>
> $AX \le b$

Has a dual

> min $b'Y$
>
> $A'Y=c$
>
> $y \ge 0$

Notice that in the third last onee I do not have a restriction on X, and in the last one we have an equality not an inequality, are these two representations equal? Is it a way to prove they are?

Comment: Are the links posted [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/320022/147263) helpful?

Comment: It's useful to know the general dual problem construction in convex optimization, which is presented in [Boyd and Vandenberghe](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf) for example.  You can use it to derive dual problems for linear programs.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the following table. 
[image]

If the restrictions have the relation sign $\geq $ in the max-problem, then the dual-variables (min-Problem) has to be $y\leq 0$ (row 8 of the table)

And it should be $A'y\geq c$, because $x \geq 0$ (row 9 of the table)